# finding constant in the bound for the geometric random variable

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables, expected-value

It was shown here [Moments of Geometric Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718350/moments-of-geometric-random-variable/718395#718395) that if $X$ is a geometric random variable, i.e. it represents the number of consecutive failures before you get the first success, where the success probability is $\rho$, there exists absolute constants $C_k$ such that
$$
E(X^k)\leqslant\frac{C_k}{\varrho^k},
$$

Is it possible to find this constant, preferably the smallest possible?

Comment: do you want to find any C_k that satisfies that bound, or the smallest such value?

Comment: The smallest possible would be better.